# YouCompleteMe: How to define special keyword?

Tags: keyword

For example, I need to type `(others => '0')` many times.
Can I define `(others => '0')` as a keyword. If I type something like `other` then `(others => '0')` will show in the selection menu.

Comment: You should check out Snipmate or Ultisnips for this. They let you define patterns like this, so you can type "other<Tab>" and it'll complete to the full pattern. FWIW, you CAN make YouCompleteMe show snippet completions in addition to other candidates.

Comment: @tandrewnichols Yes, it's super easy to do this with Snipmate. Thanks a lot!